Dates mismatch in DataFrame - Data alignment
I'm seeking assistance with a date mismatch issue in my pandas DataFrame. I appreciate any insights you can provide.
enter image description here
I've attached an image showing a subset of my DataFrame. The full DataFrame contains about 98 columns, with each pair of columns representing a stock's dates and values. The issue I'm facing is that some stocks have data starting later (e.g., in 2019 or 2020) instead of the earliest date (13/01/2018).
My objectives are to:

Align the data across all stocks by shifting down the data for stocks that are not aligned with the earliest date.
Aggregate the data, keeping only the first 'Dates' column.

Additional information:

The data is weekly, so sometimes 12/01/2018 needs to be aligned with the closest date (e.g., 13/01/2018) for a particular stock.

I need to do that in Python please.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to approach this problem efficiently.
date_columns = [col for col in df.columns if 'Dates' in col]
value_columns = [col for col in df.columns if 'Dates' not in col]

for date_col in date_columns:
    df[date_col] = pd.to_datetime(df[date_col], errors='coerce')

df_combined = pd.DataFrame()
df_combined['Common Date'] = df[date_columns[0]]

for i in range(1, len(date_columns)):
    df_combined['Common Date'] = df_combined['Common Date'].combine_first(df[date_columns[i]])

df_combined = df_combined.drop_duplicates(subset=['Common Date']).sort_values('Common Date').reset_index(drop=True)

for date_col, value_col in zip(date_columns, value_columns):
    df_combined[value_col] = df[value_col]

df_combined


Hi, welcome to SO! Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to identify/display the stock value of different companies on the same/similar dates? Thanks!

Hello, Thank you in advance.
Yes, you are right. I have multiple columns in my data set, and each two pairs correspond to dates and the stock's PE ratio on that date, the problem is that not all stocks start at the same date as you can see, so I am trying to align them.

aligning them to what exactly, and how to deal with exceptions  .... the request needs clarification, examples of this 'alignment' and also when things cannot be aligned, suggest you rethink your request. Additionally, please, do not post images - they are not helpful (unless an actual image), copy/paste text data as text.
